# How to get the inlines styles as JS object set via style attribute?

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the inlines styles set via style attribute as JS object. For e.g in following html I would like to fetch the `#box` div styles attribute value as `{width: "300px" , color: "red" }` (js object)

HTML

```
<div id="box" style="width: 300px; color: red">Box</div>
```

If I directly access the style object of the dom object, the object returned is CSSStyleDeclaration, which is not what I want:

```
var para = document.getElementById('box') 
console.dir(box.style)
```

[image]

Also using `window.getComputedStyle()` is not an option because the target object is a clone of a dom element which has not been mounted yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getAttribute` to get the string attribute, then split by `;`s to turn it into the desired format:

```js
const styleProps = Object.fromEntries(
  box.getAttribute('style')
    .split(/; +/)
    .map(str => str.split(/: */))
);
console.log(styleProps);
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 300px; color: red">Box</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach that will only give you valid values that the browser understands (instead of simply parsing a string.) This solution iterates over the style object of an element to build the object:

```
const para = document.getElementById('box')

const styleObj = Array.from(para.style).reduce((style, name) => {
  style[name] = para.style[name]
  return style
}, {})
```

The problem with parsing a string and splitting is that any invalid values will also be used. So the example below will give you back `{ width: 'foobar' }` which is clearly invalid.

```
<div id="box" style="width: foobar">Box</div>
```